# Rails thread sleep after saving record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord

When I try to call record.save! inside of a thread, the thread sleeps. I need to use a thread for an rspec test.

```
a = Thread.new do
  t = User.find(1)
  t.role = 2
  t.save!
end
```

This is the output I receive in my console

> Thread:0x007fe1d68d9978@(pry):125 **sleep** [32] pry(main)>   User Load
>   (8.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
>   (0.1ms)  BEGIN    (0.2ms)  COMMIT

Comment: Why do you need threads for RSpec? What do you try to achieve? How does your test look like?

Comment: Looks like the role is already set to 2, so no update is performed

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `join` on the thread.  You need to call `a.join` somewhere in order to let the main process know to run your thread.

From the docs...

> Then we are able to pause the execution of the main thread and allow our new thread to finish, using join. If we don't call join before the main thread terminates, then all other threads will be killed.

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Thread.html

Comment: It seems like this wasn't my problem. I have a .with_lock running in my thread which causes this to happen 

Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: